# Console hex/ASCII editor with a cut function

Tags: gratis, linux, command-line, binary-data, editor

Can you recommend a free console hex/ASCII editor with a decent cut function (which would allow to cut blocks e.g. from the middle of a file)? Something which wouldn't be blue all over the place like Norton Commander

Comment: So you want something other than vim/emacs/nano? Why?

Comment: Since this was migrated from unix.stackexchange.com, could you please tag it appropriately as Unix or Linux, or some particular distro or packaging system? Also, please tag gratis or state a budget. Is "cut" the only feature which you require? If more, please state.them. The more information that you give us, the better we will be able to help you.  Ans, since I am quite thick - what do you mean by console? Truly command line only? No Gui? (If Gui, pelsae tag Gnome, Kde, etc)

Comment: @gardenhead: vim and emacs are a bit heavy (AFAIK nano isn't a hex editor and Emacs has a GUI). As said, I want a console application

Comment: @Mawg: the cut function seems to be the only thing what I missed in hexedit, which I'm using now. "Command line only" is vague. I want ASCII graphics, as in hexedit, norton commander or (net)hack

Answer (score 1):

### [Emacs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs) + [nhexl-mode](http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/nhexl-mode.html)

Emacs is a text editor with a lot of features and enormous extensibility.

Emacs has a built-in mode to edit binary file called [Hexl mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Editing-Binary-Files.html). However, it only supports overwriting, which is the limitation you want to overcome.

There's a package (plugin) called [nhexl-mode](http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/nhexl-mode.html) which solves this problem. You can install it through Emacs's package manager (menu “Options” → “Manage Emacs Packages”). Nhexl-mode starts in overwrite mode by default, but you can switch to insert mode by running `M-x binary-overwrite-mode RET`. Even in overwrite mode, deleting works.

You can put the following code snippet in your init file (`~/.emacs`) to bind the <kbd>Insert</kbd> key to toggling overwrite mode in nhexl-mode. (It's a bit more complex than ordinary key bindings because unlike most other modes, nhexl-mode doesn't have a specific keymap by default.)

```
(unless (boundp 'nhexl-mode-map)
  (defvar nhexl-mode-map (make-sparse-keymap)
    "Keymap used when `nhexl-mode' is active."))
(define-key nhexl-mode-map [insert] 'binary-overwrite-mode)
```

[This](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19290/nhexl-mode-shows-bytes-80-ff-with-6-digit-hex-3fff80-3fffff/19291#19291) may also be of interest if you use nhexl-mode.

Comment: While not what I asked for (Emacs has a GUI), it's good to know this too

Comment: @jaam How is it not what you asked for? (Emacs has a GUI, so what? Your question asks for something that works in a terminal, and Emacs does work in a terminal. It'll start in terminal mode if X isn't available, and you can force it to run in a terminal even if X is available with `emacs -nw`)

Comment: If so, apologies (I don't use Emacs, and assumed it's a GUI-only program). Learning Emacs to be able to cut text from the middle of a file seems a bit of an overkill (but I may be forced to it in the end)